# UITableView separator problem

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview

```
mailSubscritionTable.separatorColor = [UIColor blueColor];


- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    return 5;

}
```

but, i get more then separator here , i want that only 5 separator will shown.

Comment: AFAIK not possible. Option; make the seperator invisible and draw a custom one within your table cells.

Comment: If you don't mind rounded corners, set the table view style to Grouped.

Comment: With a Plain table view, try adding a table footer view with desired background color to prevent the empty cells from showing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's super easy:

```
tableView.tableFooterView = [[[UIView alloc] init] autorelease];
```